# Генерация последовательности уникальных случайных чисел

Tags: c#, алгоритм, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных, генераторы

Мне нужно сгенерировать последовательность уникальных случайных чисел. Я использую стандартный генератор и получаю повторы, причём довольно часто, например:

```cs
var rand = new Random();

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Console.Write(rand.Next());
    Console.Write(' ');
}
```

```
1 3 3 2 0 9 5 8 2 4 9 ...
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста ваш код, который проблема.

Comment: Ваш код пишет в файл, а нужно читать, если хотите что-то из файла получить.

Comment: @aepot Вот проблема заключается в том, что необходимо, прежде всего чтобы рандомное число записывалось, после чего при следующем проходе, файл проверился на содержание уже нового числа, если оно есть, то рандом должен сгенерировать следующее число, пока данного числа не будет в файле

Comment: А для чего это всё? Зачем файл? Отредактируйте вопрос, расскажите, что именно вы хотите сделать. А пока вы хотите странного и не совсем понятного. Вы смогли записать файл, и не можете прочитать его?

Comment: держите все элементы к коллекции, проверяйте новое число на вхождение в коллекцию, логика та же, при необходимости - пишите коллекцию в файл.

Comment: А все дело в том, что случайные числа ... случайны. Возьмите кость с 6 сторонами и бросьте раз 50, посмотрите сколько повторов там будет ;-)

Comment: @Kromster не всегда. Это же *псевдо*-случайные числа. В моем ответе в варианте #3 описан такой метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение

Тут 3 варианта: либо вам нужно шафлить последовательность чисел, либо немного посложнее, либо ещё сложнее)

### Вариант #1

```cs
public static SpanExtensions
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static readonly Random rand = new Random();

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this Span<T> list)  
    {
        var n = list.Count;

        while (count > 1)
        {
            n--;
            var k = rand.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### Вариант #2

```cs
public static SpanExtensions
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static readonly HashSet<int> usedNums = new HashSet<int>();

    public static void NextDistinctSequence(this Random random, Span<int> buffer, int minValue = -1, int maxValue = -1)
    {
        // checks

        if (buffer.IsEmpty) return;

        usedNums.EnsureCapacity(buffer.Length);

        for (var i < 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            int num;

            do
            {
            num = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
            } while (!usedNums.Add(num));

            buffer[i] = num;
        }

        usedNums.Clear();
    }
}
```

Просто берём и исключаем из последовательности уже используемые числа.

### Вариант #3

Он основывается на линейном конгруэнтном методе (ссылка #1)

```cs
public sealed class LcmRandom : Random
{
    // fields
    int cur;

    public LcmRandom(int a, int c, int m, int divisor = 1, int remeinder = 0x7fff_ffff)
    {
        // init
        cur = 1;
    }
    public LcmRandom(int divisor = 1, int remeinder = 0x4000_0000) :
        this(1103515245, 12345, 0x4000_0000, divisor, remeinder) { } // gcc impl

    public override int Next()
    {
        // checks

        cur = (cur * a + c) % m;

        return (cur / divisor) % remeinder;
    }
}
```

Его прикол в том, что если `m & (m - 1) == 0` (т. е. `m` – это степень 2-ки), то данный алгоритм генерирует последовательность размером в `m` из уникальных чисел. Т. е. его нужно использовать примерно вот так: меняете `Random` -> `LcmRandom` и всё!

## Ссылки

- [Ссылка #1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4) – Wikipedia: Линейный конгруэнтный метод